# How can I prove that these integrals do not converge?

Tags: integration, divergent-series

Can you please help me to prove the integrals
\begin{equation*}
\int_0^\pi \frac{x}{\sin(x)}~\text{and}~\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\cos(x^{-1})
\end{equation*}
are divergent? Please I really need it.

Thank you.

Comment: 2) need other brackets ..

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

- the first : When $x \to \pi$, we have $\sin x = \sin (\pi -x) \sim \pi - x$ and $\int_1^{\pi} \frac{\pi}{\pi -x}$ diverges.